# How to modify stream on ongoing connection to pause/resume stream transmission

Tags: socket.io, webrtc, peerjs

I recently started learning and building an app for my school for remote online classes with WebRTC and PeerJs on my school's server (VPS). So far I am able to set up 1 to 1 peer connection but having a hard time pausing and resuming stream transmission.

I am seeking some help on how to pause and resume video and audio stream for self and remote user, while on active connection. When I execute `localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false`, it only disable video for me (not for a remote user).

As some have suggested [replaceTrack API](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dom-rtcrtpsender-replacetrack), but I am not unable to find tutorials about it as I am new to it.

My code (Thanks to [Link](https://github.com/spine001/working_peer_js_WebRTC_Nodejs_example)) looks like below:

```
var url = new URL(window.location.href)
var disableStreamInBeginning = url.searchParams.get("disableStreamInBeginning")
var passwordProtectedRoom = url.searchParams.get("passwordProtectedRoom")
var muteAllInBeginning = url.searchParams.get("muteAllInBeginning")
var isVideoCall = url.searchParams.get("isVideoCall")
var singleOrConference = url.searchParams.get("singleOrConference")

const conferenceView = document.getElementById('conference')
const loader = document.getElementById('loader')
const localVideoView = document.getElementById('local-video')
const remoteVideoView = document.getElementById('remote-video')
const remoteVideoDiv = document.getElementById('remote-video-div')
if(typeof disableStreamInBeginning !== 'undefined' && disableStreamInBeginning == 'true'){
    var disbaleSelfStream = true
} else {
    var disbaleSelfStream = false
}
if(typeof passwordProtectedRoom !== 'undefined' && passwordProtectedRoom == 'true'){
    var passwordProtected = true
} else {
    var passwordProtected = false
}
if(typeof muteAllInBeginning !== 'undefined' && muteAllInBeginning == 'true'){
    var muteAll = true
} else {
    var muteAll = false
}
if(typeof isVideoCall !== 'undefined' && isVideoCall == 'true'){
    var videoCall = true
} else {
    var videoCall = false
}
if(typeof singleOrConference !== 'undefined' && singleOrConference == 'conference'){
    var isConference = true
    conferenceView.style.display = 'block'
} else {
    var isConference = false
    localVideoView.style.opacity = 0
    remoteVideoView.style.opacity = 0
    remoteVideoDiv.style.opacity = 0
}

var selectedCamera = 'user'
let localStream;

const socket = io('/');
localVideoView.muted = true;
const peers = {};
const peer = new Peer(undefined, {
    host: '/',
    port: '443',
    path: '/myapp',
    secure: true
})

// Handelling incoming call connection
peer.on("call", async (call) => {
    let stream = null;
    try {
        stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
            {
                video: {
                    facingMode: selectedCamera
                },
                audio: true
            });
        call.answer(stream);
        call.on("stream", (remoteVideoStream) => {
            addVideoStream(remoteVideoView, remoteVideoStream);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('peer.on("call": ' + err);
    };
});

// On new user connected
socket.on("user-connected", async (userId) => {
    connectDataToNewUser(userId);
    try {
        stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
            {
                audio: true,
                video: true,
            })
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('socket.on("user-connected": ' + err);
    };
    connectMediaToNewUser(userId, stream);
});

// Show  own Video on own device screen
(async () => {
    try {
        localStream= await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
            {
                video: {
                    facingMode: selectedCamera
                },
                audio: true
            });
            addVideoStream(localVideoView, localStream);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('(async () =>: ' + err);
    }
})();

peer.on("open", (id) => {
    socket.emit("join-room", ROOM_ID, id);
});

peer.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log('peer.on("error": ' + err);
})

socket.on("user-disconnected", (userId) => {
    if (peers[userId]) {
        peers[userId].close();
    }
});

// Set up event listener for an "another user" data connection established event
peer.on("connection", (conn) => {
    conn.on("data", (data) => {
        console.log('Received data ' + data);
    });
    // Set up event listener for connection conn established event
    conn.on("open", () => {
        conn.send('Hello!');
    });
});

// Initiate a Data call (Messages) to user
const connectDataToNewUser = (userId) => {
    let conn = peer.connect(userId);
    conn.on("data", (data) => {
        console.log('Received data: ' + data);
    });
    conn.on("open", () => {
        conn.send('hi!');
    });
};

// Initiate a Media call (Audio/Video) to user
const connectMediaToNewUser = (userId, stream) => {
    const call = peer.call(userId, stream);
    call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
        addVideoStream(remoteVideoView, userVideoStream);
    });
    call.on("close", () => {
        remoteVideoView.remove();
    });
    call.on("error", (error) => {
        console.log('connectMediaToNewUser' + error);
    });
    peers[userId] = call;
};

const addVideoStream = (video, stream) => {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
        if(disbaleSelfStream){
            systemStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false
            systemStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false
        } else {
            loader.style.opacity = 0
            video.style.opacity = 1
            video.play()
            remoteVideoDiv.style.opacity = 0
        }
    });
};
```

Server Side Code:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const httpPort = process.env.PORT || 80
const httpsPort = 443
const { ExpressPeerServer } = require('peer')
const path = require('path')
const http = require('http')
const https = require('https')
const fs = require('fs')

// Certificate & credentials
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'certs', 'key.pem'))
const certificate = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'certs', 'cert.pem'))
const credentials = {
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate
}

const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app).listen(httpsPort, () => { console.log('Peer Server listening to port ' + httpsPort) })

const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(httpsServer, {
        debug: true,
        path: '/myapp'
})

app.use(peerServer)

const io = require('socket.io')(httpsServer, {
   forceNew: true,
   transports: ["polling"],
})
const { v4: uuidV4 } = require('uuid')

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(`/${uuidV4()}`)
})

app.get('/:room', (req, res) => {
  res.render('room', { roomId: req.params.room })
})

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('join-room', (roomId, userId) => {
        socket.join(roomId)
        socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit('user-connected', userId)

        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit('user-disconnected', userId)
        })
        socket.on('text-message', message => {
            socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit('text-message-received', message)
        })
        socket.on('system-stream-updated', remoteUserId => {
            socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit('new-remote-stream', remoteUserId)
        })
    })
})
```

And room.ejs (if needed)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script>
    const ROOM_ID = "<%= roomId %>"
  </script>
  <script src="peer.min.js" defer></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" defer></script>
  <script src="client.js" defer></script>
  <title>Interface</title>
  <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .container, .local-video {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
        }
        .remote-video-div {
            position: absolute;
            max-width: 30%;
            width: 30%;
            margin: 16px;
        }
        .remote-video {
            max-width: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: -5px;
        }
        .video-inset {
            outline: unset;
            visibility: hidden;
            position: relative;
            margin:0; 
            padding:0; 
        }
        
        .background-black {
            background-color: #000000 !important;
        }
        
        .display-none {
            display: none;
        }
        
        .loader {
            margin: 250px auto;
            border: 7px solid #9e9c9c;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border-top: 7px solid #ffffff;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
            animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
        /* Safari */
        @-webkit-keyframes spin {
            0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
            100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
        }

        @keyframes spin {
            0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
            100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
        }
  </style>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="local-video-div background-black">
        <video class="local-video" autoplay></video>
    </div>
    <div class="container background-black display-none" id="loader">
        <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="remote-video-div background-black">
        <video class="remote-video" autoplay onclick="remoteVideoClick()"></video>
    </div>
    <div class="container background-black display-none" id="conference">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Julio Spinelli, looking forward for your help.

Comment: So you need to make one way call with peerjs as well? Because your current code will work with two way streaming.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and was looking for a solution. It's funny because your question itself solved my issue! I did this ...

```
 <button
        onClick={() =>
          (stream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled =
            !stream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled)
        }
  >
```

---

By the way as you might have noticed (from the "on**C**lick") that I am doing this on react. In your case, however, I think you should get the video stream from the device first and set it into a variable. Then call the user with that stream variable and when you need it, you can stop and start the streaming by doing stream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = !stream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled. But, make sure you have one source of truth for the stream and always reference it from there. I did this in react and it's working for me. Hope that it does for you too!